# VS 2012 invalid compile errors. Only way to fix is to wait like an hour

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, compilation, build-error

I am getting some really weird issues.

In VS2012:

I copy the code from an existing page to a new page, make some changes. Then change the referenced user control to a control that does not exist yet.

Then create the new user control and paste code from another control, make some changes and save.

VS will fail to build because of 'xxx' not declared errors. Which is bogus they are declared.

restart VS, restart machine, build, rebuild, clean and rebuild. All fails to fix the errors.

BUT, after a seemingly random amount of time (like, hours), the problem will fix itself.

I can't wait hours every time. How can I tell VS to stop being silly and build the project! Anybody know why it is failing?

Comment: Are you sure your project / solution has finished compiling?  Check the output window.  Also, you haven't said whether you're using Win Forms, Web Forms, WPF or something else.

Comment: Yeah it finishes compiling in about 2 seconds! Using ASP.net with VB.net

Comment: Have you tried compiling fron the command line, using MSBuild?